# Positioning elements in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I have class for a cell

```swift
import UIKit

class LinkCellView: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagsListView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image: Table View Cell in IB]

I fill the `tagsListView` in `cellForRowAt`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "linkCell", for: indexPath) as! LinkCellView
    let object = links[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellTitleLabel!.text = object.description
    let tag = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    tag.text = "Frkul"
    cell.tagsListView.addSubview(tag)

    return cell
}
```

Unfortunately when I then run the app in simulator, list of tags is just barely visible there. My expectation is to see the whole tags list.

[image: Resulting cell on iOS]

I am pretty new to iOS development, so it is possible I am missing some fundamental knowledge of designing iOS UI. If it is not possible to answer this question directly, pls point me to a tutorial / webinar taking newbies through this topic.

- Xcode Version 10.0
- iOS 12
- iOS simulator Version 10.0

Static version of the App — https://gitlab.com/lipoqil/stackview-in-table-cell

Comment: share constraints for every item in the cell

Comment: I updated the IB screenshot

Comment: Use autolayout instead of CGRect

Comment: @codeByThey Sry, I need example. I don't know what does it mean what you wrote.

Comment: I added link to static demo of the App

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for some reason, if I use `UIStackView`, instead of `UIView`, it displays almost as I wish.

[image: Table rows in simulator]

It introduces one change in the code

`cell.tagListView.addSubview(tag)` → `cell.tagListView.addArrangedSubview(tag)`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "linkCell", for: indexPath) as! LinkCellView
    cell.tagListView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    let object = links[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellTitleLabel!.text = object.description
    let tag = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    tag.shadowColor = .blue
    tag.text = object.tags
    cell.tagListView.addArrangedSubview(tag)

    return cell
}
```

I still need to solve, how to fit the tags there, how to make its look more tagish, but I believe that's beyond the original question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a collection of tags you need to implement a collection view into your tableView Cell, and if you just have 1 tag, just implement it in your xib ?

Comment: It seems to me collection view is for grid visualisation of a data. As the tags will vary in length, I don't UICollectionView to be a good fit for this task. Or is it somehow possible to make it non-grid? Sry for dumb questions, almost everything is new for me in iOS development 

Comment: yes of course it is possible! UI collection view is a kinda Scrolling view which supports horizontal scrolling and in fact, the grids are also collection views with vertical scrolling direction, and it looks actually grid because of sizing the width of each cell, for example u can set each cell's width = screenWidth/3 for or any number, I have also used collection views for dynamic tags, or showing winners list and .... in my apps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
func numberOfSections(in tagsCV: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ tagsCV: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videoObject?.tags?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ tagsCV: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: StylesBook.hashtag.value.textFont]
    let size = (videoObject?.tags?[indexPath.row] ?? "" as String).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
    return CGSize(width: size.width + CGFloat(20) , height: 50)

}

func collectionView(_ tagsCV: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = tagsCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TagCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCollectionViewCell
    cell.tagBtn.setTitle(englishNumToPersian(text: videoObject?.tags?[indexPath.row] ?? "")  , for: .normal)
    cell.tagBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tagTaped(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
    return cell
}
```

The key is that you need to set ur collection view's scroll direction `horizontal`. This way whether you have 1 or 1000 tag, they'll all be shown perfectly, and the button (or label) width will fit its content. I recommend you to use button, instead of label, and disable its user interaction to act like a label.

Comment: I don't think I am able to make this go. I ended up with app which fails shortly after it's launched with uncaught exception which doesn't tell me anything. You can check — https://gitlab.com/lipoqil/stackview-in-table-cell/compare/master...collection-view